# Scroll to bottom listener Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a page that I want to be scrollable (mostly text only, no list). At the bottom of that page I have a disabled button, but when I reach the bottom of the page I want that button to activate. How can I do this with JetpackCompose Kotlin androidx.compose.ui version 1.3.2?

Much appreciation in advance!

I can't use `ScrollableColumn`, `Scrollable`, `LazyColumn`, `LazyRow` because of the compose library.

Comment: Isn't `ScrollableColumn` part of the Jetpack Compose library?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear why you can't use these components since they are all part of the Compose library. However, this can be done using Column composable with verticalScroll modifier.

```
val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
Column(Modifier.verticalScroll(scrollState)) {
        //Text
    }
```

State for enabling Button, false by default:

```
val isButtonEnabled by remember {mutableStateOf(false)}
```

ScrollState has `canScrollForward` Boolean property, `false` means we cannot scroll forward (we are the end of the list). Once we have `false` here, button should be enabled

```
LaunchedEffect(scrollState.canScrollForward) {
    if (!scrollState.canScrollForward) isButtonEnabled = true
}
```

And button:

```
Button(enabled = isButtonEnabled, ...)
```

Comment: You don't need a side effect. Just use `enabled = !scrollState.canScrollForward`

Comment: @Gabriele Mariotti In this case if the user scrolls down to the end, and then up a little, the button will not become disabled again?

Comment: Ok. It depends on the final goal. If the button has to be enabled only if the list reaches the end on always after the list is scrolled to the end once.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Vertically scrollable component was measured with an infinity maximum height constraints, which is disallowed.  I do get this error for the solution above.

Comment: This means that the column is inside another vertically scrolling component. And this won't work. To suggest any solution, we need to see the current structure of the composition.

Comment: I've put the code below.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Composable
override fun Build() {

    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
    val isButtonEnabled by remember {mutableStateOf(false)}
    LaunchedEffect(scrollState.canScrollForward) {
        if (!scrollState.canScrollForward) isButtonEnabled = true
    }

    ScreenScaffold(
        header = {
            TopBar(
                title = R.string.insurance_choose_insurance_travel,
                onBack = { sendNavEffect.invoke(Effect.Navigation.OnBack) },
                actions = {},
                backgroundColor = white
            )
        },
        page = {
            Column(
                Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(20.dp)
                    .verticalScroll(scrollState)
            ){
                repeat(100){
                    Text(
                        "Text",
                        color = Color.Black
                    )
                }
            }
        },
        footer = {
            Row(modifier = Modifier.padding(20.dp)) {
                PrimaryActionButton(
                    text = R.string.accept_terms_and_conditions_sca.getString(),
                    buttonState = if(isButtonEnabled) ButtonState.Active else ButtonState.Disabled,
                    onClick = {}
                )
            }
        })
}
```

}

Comment: Tried to adjust my code with your solution @bylazy, but it's not working. I don't exactly know what I did wrong, maybe if you can help me.

Comment: This code is incomplete, it won't compile. So I won't be able to reproduce the error. Why is fun Build is marked as override? What is ScreenScaffold? If I take only Column part it works fine.